# Is xs:language datatype inconsistently defined by W3C?

Tags: xsd

According to [Section 3.3.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#language) of the W3C Datatypes spec:

> language represents natural language identifiers as defined by
>   [RFC 3066]. The value space of language is the set of all strings 
>   that are valid language identifiers as defined [RFC 3066]. The
>   lexical space of language is the set of all strings that conform to
>   the pattern [a-zA-Z]{1,8}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8})*

However, in [RFC 3066](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt) it states in Section 2.5 that

> ```
>         language-range  = language-tag / "*"
> ```
>
> That is, a language-range has the same syntax as a language-tag, or
>     is the single character "*".
>   where
>     The special range "*" matches any tag.

Thus, the RFC would allow the use of the astrick as a wildcard identifying all possible languages. However, the pattern specified by W3C does not allow the use of "*". In other words, it appears that the lexical space and the value space are disjoint. Alternatively, I could be misunderstanding something in the definitions. Hence my question: Is the xs:language datatype inconsistently defined by W3C?

Comment: Since neither `language-range` nor `language-tag` specify that they are a language *identifier*, why is one of them (the one you're currently looking at) the *correct* reference to assume? Why aren't you looking at `language-tag` as the standing for "language identifiers"?

Comment: However, since the RFC's title is "Tags for the Identification of Languages", I'd certainly think that the `language-tag` definition is the *more important* in this RFC than the `language-range` one.

Comment: I agree that the uncertainty of what is meant by "language identifier" is at the heart of the problem. IMHO a _range_ qualifies as an identifier. Of course, that may simply be bias (or wishful thinking) on my part since my application requires the ability to specify large sets of languages up to an including all known ones.

Comment: Range, to me, implies "more than one" (or at least, the scope for such). Identifier is usually used in *singular* contexts.